# Unity Wwise. No audio in my game build

Tags: unity, audio, wwise

I'm building a game in Unity using Wwise as the audio engine. I'm on a Mac and whenever I build the game, there is no audio. Apparently this is because the sound banks are not in the correct folder. They should be in Assets/StreamingAssets/Audio/GeneratedSoundBanks/ followed by a sub-folder with the name of whatever platform you are using. I should have a Mac folder located here however there isn't one. Instead my sound banks just sit in the GeneratedSoundBanks folder which works when i test the game in unity, however there is no audio when I build the game. Apparently this has something to do with environment variables or a python path but I have no idea how to fix or edit these as I am new to coding as well as Wwise and Unity. If I build the game for web player I get an error CS0246: The type of namespace name 'AKRESULT'  could not be found. Web GL says it doesn't work for the unity wise integration package I have either (and going to an older one just messed my whole projects audio up completely). If anyone could give me any help at all, it would be very much appreciated. Thank You.

I'm using: Unity 5.3.5.1f, Wwise v2016.1 (32-bit), WwiseUnityIntergration_v2016.1_Mac.unitypackage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the `GeneratedSoundbanks` folder in your Wwise project, and paste it into the `Assets/StreamingAssets/Audio/` directory of your Unity project before running the build process in Unity.

Comment: Thanks so much Kam, that was so frustrating. Builds for Mac and Windows work perfectly now. Just need a web build solution now.